# A real function compose a harmonic function is harmonic iff it is linear

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

> Let $u$ be a harmonic function on region $D$, $\phi$ is r a real function on $u(D)$. Prove that $\phi \circ u$ is harmonic on $D$ iff $\phi$ is linear.

I have tried to write an analytic function $f$ with $u$ be its real part and tried to find some properties of $\phi \circ f$. Does this approach correct? What else should I do? Thanks for any help.

Comment: With $g=\phi o u$ obtain $g_{xx}$ and $g_{yy}$ then use harmonicity of $u$.

Comment: @MyGlasses can you write more explicitly? I'm unfamiliar with the partial calculations.

Comment: What if $u$ is constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We obtain
$$g_{xx}=\dfrac{d^2\phi}{du^2}.\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+\dfrac{d\phi}{du}.\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}$$
$$g_{yy}=\dfrac{d^2\phi}{du^2}.\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2+\dfrac{d\phi}{du}.\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}$$
then $g=\phi o u$ is harmonic iff $g_{xx}+g_{yy}=0$ iff 
$$\dfrac{d^2\phi}{du^2}.\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+\dfrac{d\phi}{du}.\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}
+
\dfrac{d^2\phi}{du^2}.\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2+\dfrac{d\phi}{du}.\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}=0$$
iff (since $u$ is harmonic)
$$\dfrac{d^2\phi}{du^2}[\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2]=0$$
iff
$\phi$ be linear.

Comment: Hmm ... we don't even know $\phi$ is differentiable, do we?

Comment: @zhw. Good point. Thanks.